# Send a private message to a specific username with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know a user's Discord username (like something#0000) and I know that my bot shares a guild with that user. Without any kind of prompt (like on_message), I just want to send a private message to that user. It seems the type that contains the right method is `discord.member.Member`, so I guess my question is how can I produce that type if I know the username?

There are a few questions here that deal with sending the DM based on a specific prompt, like a command or a message that the bot receives, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I also don't want to use the guild object to pull up the member. The only thing I can go by is the username. Not sure why I had to specify this multiple times, but here it is, I edited it to explain how the question is different.

couple of things I tried:

```
await client.fetch_user("username#0000") #this results in discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035)
```

and using get_user instead of fetch_user produces a None type.

Any help would be valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clarify how exactly you want to send DM to a user. Is it a command, some reaction on their message, button, event, just schedule/timed task, etc ? I mean that it's not `on_message` doesn't really clarify your intentions.

Anyway, to send DM you can use `.send` method from [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=find#discord.Member) class and thus if you already have it from `ctx`/`interaction`/`event` - you can just use it.

If it is a task without any starting point then we can use `.send` from `discord.User`. I would suggest using [`discord.utils.find`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=find#discord.utils.find) to find said `user` and then use `await user.send`

so MRE would be something like.

```py
    @tasks.loop(count=1) #dont forget to start the task properly
    async def send_annoying_message(self):
        user = discord.utils.find(lambda m: str(m) == 'username#0000', self.bot.users)
        await user.send('hello')
```

Comment: This line: 
user = discord.utils.find(lambda m: str(m) == 'username#0000', self.bot.users)
results in AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

I replaced self.bot with client (which is made this way client = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix='.')
And of course the username with a real one that exists in the server (my username)

Comment: "> If an entry is not found, then None is returned." - from docs. meaning there is no username#0000 that shares guild with the bot

Comment: well I'm pretty sure I'm in the server with the bot. I used my username. I put the code in the on_ready method

Comment: it s hard to poke at this from my perspective because It works on my bot with my username just fine... Well, first thought to check would be member intents that you need to optin on dev portal.

Comment: well, I appreciate the effort. I do have the servers member intent turned on. But when I go to print(client.users), I just get the bot itself, and no one else. This is the output  [<ClientUser id=919695698016997426 name='actual.monster' discriminator='1996' bot=True verified=True mfa_enabled=False>]

Comment: Okay, let's double check. You also should turn intents on in the code itself. `commands.Bot(intents=intents, ...` --- what exactly `intents` variable here is. Is it `discord.Intents.default()` ? If so, then it doesnt have `members` intents on. Try `discord.Intents.all()`

Answer (score 0):

The [fetch_user()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch%20user#discord.Client.fetch_user) function works only if there's a User ID provided, basically the 18-digit number in which you can find by right clicking on a user's profile and selecting 'Copy ID', this option is available if the [Developer Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/714348/how-to-enable-or-disable-developer-mode-on-discord/) on Discord is ON.

[Edit - Added How to Send a Message]

```
# Get the user first 
user = await client.fetch_user(USER_ID)
await user.send("Hello!")
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you also want to answer the question about how to send a message?

Comment: Just edited my og answer! Hope it helps~

Comment: Except I don't have the user ID, I just have the username (tag) in this format username#0000

Comment: You can get the user ID by right clicking on your profile and if you have Developer Mode On. Please Check this Article:
https://www.howtogeek.com/714348/how-to-enable-or-disable-developer-mode-on-discord/

Comment: I'm not trying to get one specific ID. I want it to work dynamically for any user, based on the logic in the app

Comment: You can get it working on any user, if it's by message, you can get the member id by 
`message.author.id`

Comment: I specified in the question that it's not prompted by anything. Not by a message, not by a server join, I just want to send that message based exclusively on the logic in my python app